# How to fix react-navigation/native download error - fixes needed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, navigation, stack-navigator

thanks for taking your time to read this.

What's happening is that I'm trying to use the stack navigator for a CLI react native project, but I think I'm not able to download the react-navigation package. When I use the command **npm install react-navigation/native** inside the visual studio terminal, I get this message:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve   
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: Pup@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: @react-navigation/native@6.0.11
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-navigation/native
npm ERR!   peer @react-navigation/native@"^6.0.0" from @react-navigation/elements@1.3.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/elements
npm ERR!     @react-navigation/elements@"^1.3.4" from @react-navigation/native-stack@6.7.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@react-navigation/native-stack
npm ERR!       @react-navigation/native-stack@"^6.7.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @react-navigation/native@"^6.0.0" from @react-navigation/native-stack@6.7.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/native-stack
npm ERR!     @react-navigation/native-stack@"^6.7.0" from the root projectnpm ERR!   1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @react-navigation/native@"react-navigation/native" from the root 
project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @react-navigation/core@3.7.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-navigation/core
npm ERR!   peer @react-navigation/core@"^3.0.0" from @react-navigation/native@3.6.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/native
npm ERR!     @react-navigation/native@"react-navigation/native" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\sergi\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sergi\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-20T20_17_39_891Z-debug-0.log
```

so I tried to restart Metro with **$ npx react-native start** inside the windows terminal, and it sends :

```
 BUNDLE  ./index.js

error: Error: Unable to resolve module react-navigation/native from C:\Users\sergi\projects\Pup\src\screens\SignInScreen\SignInScreen.js: react-navigation/native could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
   5 | import CustomButton from '../../components/CustomButton';
   6 | import SocialSignInButtons from '../../components/SocialSignInButtons';
>  7 | import {useNavigation} from 'react-navigation/native';
     |                              ^
   8 | import {useForm, Controller} from 'react-hook-form';
   9 |
  10 | const SignInScreen = () => {
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\sergi\Projects\Pup\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:158:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\sergi\Projects\Pup\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:231:43)
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\sergi\Projects\Pup\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:129:24)
    at resolve (C:\Users\sergi\Projects\Pup\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:396:33)
    at C:\Users\sergi\Projects\Pup\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:412:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (C:\Users\sergi\Projects\Pup\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:411:33)
    at processModule (C:\Users\sergi\Projects\Pup\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:140:31)
    at async addDependency (C:\Users\sergi\Projects\Pup\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:230:18)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
 BUNDLE  ./index.js

error: Error: Unable to resolve module react-navigation/native from C:\Users\sergi\projects\Pup\src\screens\SignInScreen\SignInScreen.js: react-navigation/native could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
   5 | import CustomButton from '../../components/CustomButton';
   6 | import SocialSignInButtons from '../../components/SocialSignInButtons';
>  7 | import {useNavigation} from 'react-navigation/native';
     |                              ^
   8 | import {useForm, Controller} from 'react-hook-form';
   9 |
  10 | const SignInScreen = () => {
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\sergi\Projects\Pup\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:158:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\sergi\Projects\Pup\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:231:43)
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\sergi\Projects\Pup\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:129:24)
    at resolve (C:\Users\sergi\Projects\Pup\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:396:33)
    at C:\Users\sergi\Projects\Pup\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:412:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (C:\Users\sergi\Projects\Pup\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:411:33)
    at processModule (C:\Users\sergi\Projects\Pup\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:140:31)
    at async addDependency (C:\Users\sergi\Projects\Pup\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:230:18)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
```

I also attached an image from the emulator error message.

### What I tried from other stack answers already was:

"

1. Delete your package-lock.json
2. Delete your node_modules folder
3. Try npm install again

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMNlf.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete your node_modules folder
2. npm i or yarn
3. expo start -c or npx react-native start --reset-cache

Documentation you can refer to :
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting/